# Generar una lista que puede contener objetos en C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net

Amigos

Tengo una lista que ontengo de un store procedure en sql server, esta lista contiene los producto y sus caracteristicas

Ejemplo lista
[image: Ejemplo de lista]

deseo pasar esta lista a una lista mas pequeña para pasar al fron la cual contenga la lista de los productos pero el item caracteristica sea un objeto de cada producto.

Suena a algo facil pero no he podido lograr lo que deseo

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon lo que has intentado, explicate mejor

Comment: Te recomiendo leer esto y luego editar tu pregunta (quita la imagen, pon la tabla en modo texto, muestra el código que has intentado, etc.): https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Para implementar lo que necesitas hay que hacer los siguientes pasos. Presta mucha atención a los comentarios en el código.

1. Primero asumiendo que este es el modelo que te retorna el store procedure.

```
/// <summary>
/// Imagino que asi es el modelo que recibes desde SQL, entonces partiendo de esto.
/// </summary>
public class DataSql
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string caracteristica { get; set; }
    public string descripcionCaract { get; set; }
}
```

2. Creamos el nuevo modelo de datos

```
namespace Datos
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Este seria tu nuevo objeto que contendra toda la información que te retorna el store procedure
    /// </summary>
    public class Data
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Este es el objeto que contendra tus valores de las caracteristicas
        /// </summary>
        public Caracteristica ObjCaracteristica = new Caracteristica();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Y esta es la clase que te permitira agregar un objeto caracteristicas con estos atributos. 
    /// </summary>
    public class Caracteristica 
    {
        public double pecio { get; set; }
        public double cantidad { get; set; }
        public bool estado { get; set; }
    }
}
```

3. Asumiendo que los datos los tienes en una lista, los enviamos a un método que será el encargado de pasar los datos al nuevo objeto o modelo creado.

```
///Imaginemos que estos son los datos que te retorna el store procedure.
                
List<DataSql> lstDataSql = new List<DataSql>();

lstDataSql.Add(new DataSql() { id = 1, nombre = "product a", caracteristica = "precio", descripcionCaract = "5" });
lstDataSql.Add(new DataSql() { id = 1, nombre = "product a", caracteristica = "cantidad", descripcionCaract = "2" });
lstDataSql.Add(new DataSql() { id = 1, nombre = "product a", caracteristica = "estado", descripcionCaract = "true" });
lstDataSql.Add(new DataSql() { id = 2, nombre = "product b", caracteristica = "precio", descripcionCaract = "20" });
lstDataSql.Add(new DataSql() { id = 2, nombre = "product b", caracteristica = "cantidad", descripcionCaract = "3" });
lstDataSql.Add(new DataSql() { id = 2, nombre = "product b", caracteristica = "estado", descripcionCaract = "true" });


///Esos datos los envias a un método para hacer este proceso de cambiarlo a la nueva lista de datos.

List<Data> newData = ProcessedData(lstDataSql);
```

4. Generamos el método que pasara los datos a tu nueva estructura y lo retornas.

```
public static List<Data> ProcessedData(List<DataSql> lstDataSql) 
        {
            try
            {
                List<Data> lstData = new List<Data>();
                Data objData = new Data();
                int IdentificadorId = 0;

                foreach(var lst in lstDataSql) 
                {
                    if (IdentificadorId == lst.id)
                    {
                        objData.id = lst.id;
                        objData.nombre = lst.nombre;

                        if (lst.caracteristica == "precio")
                            objData.ObjCaracteristica.pecio = Convert.ToDouble(lst.descripcionCaract.ToString());
                        if (lst.caracteristica == "cantidad")
                            objData.ObjCaracteristica.cantidad = Convert.ToDouble(lst.descripcionCaract.ToString());
                        if (lst.caracteristica == "estado")
                            objData.ObjCaracteristica.estado = Convert.ToBoolean(lst.descripcionCaract.ToString());

                        IdentificadorId = lst.id;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (objData != null && objData.nombre != null)
                            lstData.Add(objData);

                        objData = null;
                        objData = new Data();

                        objData.id = lst.id;
                        objData.nombre = lst.nombre;

                        if (lst.caracteristica == "precio")
                            objData.ObjCaracteristica.pecio = Convert.ToDouble(lst.descripcionCaract.ToString());
                        if (lst.caracteristica == "cantidad")
                            objData.ObjCaracteristica.cantidad = Convert.ToDouble(lst.descripcionCaract.ToString());
                        if (lst.caracteristica == "estado")
                            objData.ObjCaracteristica.estado = Convert.ToBoolean(lst.descripcionCaract.ToString());

                        IdentificadorId = lst.id;
                    }

                    IdentificadorId = lst.id;
                }
                lstData.Add(objData);

                return lstData;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Este método recibe una lista (Lista que te retorna el store procedure) y lo que hace es iterar por cada elemento de la lista, entonces al iterar lo que vamos a hacer, es ir añadiendo la información a un modelo en concreto. Se utiliza IdentificadorId para identificar si estamos en el mismo producto o si pasamos al siguiente producto, con el fin de ir añadiendo un nuevo modelo para el otro producto.

Espero esta solución te ayude.